# Wierd Issue with PWM pin

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, motor

I'm trying to run two of my motors through PWM. Here's my code -

```
#include <Servo.h>
int Lm = 11;
int Rm = 10;
int incomingByte = 0;
int pos = 0;
Servo myservo;
void setup() {
  pinMode(Rm, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Lm, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
  myservo.attach(3);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  blinkers();
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
                incomingByte = Serial.read();
  }
  if(incomingByte == 49){
    analogWrite(Rm, 128);
    analogWrite(Lm, 128);
  }
   else if(incomingByte == 48){
    analogWrite(Rm, 0);
    analogWrite(Lm, 0);
    myservo.write(0);
  }
  else if(incomingByte == 50){
    analogWrite(Rm, 0);
    analogWrite(Lm, 128);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(Lm, 0);
  }
  else if(incomingByte == 51){
    analogWrite(Rm, 128);
    analogWrite(Lm, 0);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(Rm, 0);
  }
  else if(incomingByte == 52){
    for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 10) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 10) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);
  }
}
}

void blinkers(){
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(100);
}
```

Now in this code... Lm, and Rm are my motors. The motor Lm runs perfectly fine, but Rm doesn't move at all. When I use `digitalWrite` instead, both motors work fine.

I tried running the motor in the exact same setup but this time with only the code for running the motor by PWM. The code was -

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  analogWrite(10, 128);
  delay(100);
  analogWrite(10, 0);
  delay(100);

}
```

This code worked perfectly fine.

So clearly there is an issue in the earlier code but I can't figure out what. Everything is correct in that as well but the motor refuses to move...

Can anyone tell why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a timer conflict.

The [Servo reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Servo) says: "*...use of the library disables analogWrite() (PWM) functionality on pins 9 and 10...*"

This is a picture of the pinmapping of the Arduino Uno: [PighiXXX - Uno](http://www.pighixxx.com/test/portfolio-items/uno/).
Pin 9 en 10 uses OC1A en OC1B for PWM, that is Timer1. You can't use PWM on them when the Servo is used.
Pin 11 uses OC2A for PWM, which is Timer2.

I suppose it will work if you choose another PWM pin for analogWrite. Timer0 is used for millis and therefor the PWM frequency will be different (pin 5 and 6). That is mentioned in the [analogWrite reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite). In most cases that is not a problem.
Pin 3 is a normal PWM pin.

This is a common problem. The documentation is not always clear about the use of timers and other parts of the microcontroller. Many times the source code has to be read to see what is used. In the end, you need more experienced Arduino users to spot the conflict.

Comment: Yeah I had no idea that something like this would be the reason... Thanks for the answer @Jot